# CSS border not wrapping around nested divs

Tags: html, css

Just wondering why .border will not wrap around nested divs d1, d2, d3.

The div with id main1 has a 5px solid border that I am trying to wrap around the three nested divs with ids div1, div2, div3.  Each of the nested divs have there own 2px solid border.  Seems like it should work but maybe something is getting overwritten somewhere.

[image]

```css
.border {border: 5px solid RosyBrown;}
.border-thin {border: 2px solid RosyBrown;}
div#main1 {width: 90%;margin: 0 auto 0 auto;}
div#d1 {width: 31%; float: left;}
div#d2 {width: 31%; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 3.5%;}
div#d3 {width: 31%; float: right;}

<div id="main1" class="center border">
   <p>Main</p>
     <div id="d1" class="border-thin">
       <p>d1</p>
     </div>
     <div id="d2" class="border-thin">
       <p>d2</p>
     </div>
     <div id="d3" class="border-thin">
      <p>d3</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to clear the float.

Comment: Floated elements are not considered when calculating the height of parent elements. Google for "css clearfix". Remove `<p>Main</p>` and you will see your `div#main1`'s height will totally collapse because all its children float, leaving it at a computed height of 0. Also, I highly recommend you never use id selectors in css unless you know exactly **why** you are using them.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't cleared the floats, as it doesn't take up the view's flow. Give:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent div, or you can use the `clearfix`.

```css
.border {
  border: 5px solid RosyBrown;
}
.border-thin {
  border: 2px solid RosyBrown;
}
div#main1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#d1 {
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
}
div#d2 {
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 3.5%;
}
div#d3 {
  width: 31%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main1" class="center border">
  <p>Main</p>
  <div id="d1" class="border-thin">
    <p>d1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="d2" class="border-thin">
    <p>d2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="d3" class="border-thin">
    <p>d3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: --]

Answer (score 2):

That's due to the float elements. By default they are not included in other DIVs' height.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#main1`. I know that sound strange, but it's working...